# VS Code Remote Development cannot make work

Tags: vscode-remote

I've been trying to run a remote dev container using VS Code but always get same error below:

failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: failed to do request: Head https://mcr.microsoft.com/v2/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node/manifests/0-14: proxyconnect tcp: dial tcp 192.1.65.1:3128: i/o timeout

Has anyone know how to fix it please?

Thanks,
Alexandre

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation the issue was fixed disabling the Docker Desktop experimental feature "Use new virtualisation framework" in the Mac Big Sur. All working fine now.

Thanks,
Alexandre